# How to compare two dates in a shell?

Tags: shell-script, shell, date

How can two dates be compared in a shell?

Here is an example of how I would like to use this, though it does not work as-is:

```
todate=2013-07-18
cond=2013-07-15

if [ $todate -ge $cond ];
then
    break
fi
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: What do you want to loop for? Do you mean conditional rather than loop?

Comment: Why you tagged [tag:files]? Are those dates actually file times?

Comment: Check out this on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116503/how-to-compare-two-datetime-strings-and-return-difference-in-hours-bash-shell

Answer (score 205):

The right answer is still missing:

```
todate=$(date -d 2013-07-18 +%s)
cond=$(date -d 2014-08-19 +%s)

if [ $todate -ge $cond ];
then
    break
fi
```

Note that this requires GNU date. The equivalent `date` syntax for BSD `date` (like found in OSX by default) is `date -j -f "%F" 2014-08-19 +"%s"`

Comment: Donno why someone downvoted this, it's pretty accurate and doesn't deal with concatenating ugly strings. Convert  your date to unix timestamp (in seconds), compare unix timestamps.

Comment: I think, me main advantage of this solution is, that you can do additions or subtractions easily. For example, I wanted to have a timeout of x seconds, but my first idea (`timeout=$(\`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S\` + 500)`) is obviously wrong.

Comment: You can include nanoseconds precision with `date -d 2013-07-18 +%s%N`

Comment: It's probably better to use `(( ... > ... ))` than `[ ... -gt ... ]` or similar.  `[[ "$x" -lt "$y" ]]` returns true when $x is empty, in fact `[[ "" -eq 0 ]]` is TRUE.  If something goes wrong populating $x and it winds up empty, I'd want `"" < 1` to return false.  `(( "$x" < "$y" ))` properly errors when $x is empty without needing extra checks.

Comment: @Nicholi it's downvoted because it doesn't work, I get an error saying command not found. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle Do you mean command `date`? Which platform you are using?

Comment: Nevermind it was the fact that it needs a space between the variables and the brackets on either side, so rigid.

Answer (score 61):

Can use a ksh-style string comparison to compare the chronological ordering [of strings in a year, month, day format].

```
date_a=2013-07-18
date_b=2013-07-15

if [[ "$date_a" > "$date_b" ]] ;
then
    echo "break"
fi
```

Thankfully, when [strings that use the YYYY-MM-DD format] are sorted* in alphabetical order, they are also sorted* in chronological order.

(* - sorted or compared)

Nothing fancy needed in this case.  yay!

Comment: Where is the else branch here?

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me on Sierra MacOS

Comment: This is simpler that my solution of `if [ $(sed -e s/-//g <<< $todate) -ge $(sed -e s/-//g <<< $cond) ];` … This date format was designed to be sorted using standard alpha numeric sort, or for `-` to be stripped and sorted numerically.

Comment: This is far and away the smartest answer on here

Comment: Use this answer, it is far more robust as it does not rely on an external command.

Comment: That will not work in POSIX shell:

Comment: @sena You're right it won't.  So just use `[ ]` instead of `[[ ]]`.

Comment: @TrippKinetics No you can't, bash treats as a redirection. `[ "0" > "1" ] && echo ok` gives you ok, and creates the file `1`.

Comment: @elboulangero The correct syntax for `[ ]` would be `-gt`.  Of course, this requires the dates to be numbers, so no dashes.

Comment: @TrippKinetics I just realized that you can also quote the `>`, so `[ 2023-02-15 \> 2023-01-01 ] && echo ok` works.

Answer (score 40):

You are missing the date format for the comparison:

```
#!/bin/bash

todate=$(date -d 2013-07-18 +"%Y%m%d")  # = 20130718
cond=$(date -d 2013-07-15 +"%Y%m%d")    # = 20130715

if [ $todate -ge $cond ]; #put the loop where you need it
then
 echo 'yes';
fi
```

You are missing looping structures too, how are you planning to get more dates?

Comment: This doesn't work with the `date` shipped with macOS.

Comment: `date -d` is non standard and does not work on a typical UNIX. On BSD it even attempts to set the kenel value `DST`.

Comment: The above works if you use `gdate` on macos, it's available in brew.

Answer (score 9):

This is not a problem of looping structures but of data types.

Those dates (`todate` and `cond`) are strings, not numbers, so you cannot use the "-ge" operator of `test`. (Remember that square bracket notation is equivalent to the command `test`.)

What you can do is use a different notation for your dates so that they are integers. For example:

```
date +%Y%m%d
```

will produce an integer like 20130715 for July 15th, 2013. Then you can compare your dates with "-ge" and equivalent operators.

**Update:** if your dates are given (e.g. you are reading them from a file in 2013-07-13 format) then you can preprocess them easily with tr.

```
$ echo "2013-07-15" | tr -d "-"
20130715
```

Answer (score 8):

The operator `-ge` only works with integers, which your dates aren't.

If your script is a bash or ksh or zsh script, you can use the `<` operator instead. This operator is not available in dash or other shells that don't go much beyond the POSIX standard.

```
if [[ $cond < $todate ]]; then break; fi
```

In any shell, you can convert the strings to numbers while respecting the order of dates simply by removing the dashes.

```
if [ "$(echo "$todate" | tr -d -)" -ge "$(echo "$cond" | tr -d -)" ]; then break; fi
```

Alternatively, you can go traditional and use the `expr` utility.

```
if expr "$todate" ">=" "$cond" > /dev/null; then break; fi
```

As invoking subprocesses in a loop can be slow, you may prefer to do the transformation using shell string processing constructs.

```
todate_num=${todate%%-*}${todate#*-}; todate_num=${todate_num%%-*}${todate_num#*-}
cond_num=${cond%%-*}${cond#*-}; cond_num=${cond_num%%-*}${cond_num#*-}
if [ "$todate_num" -ge "$cond_num" ]; then break; fi
```

Of course, if you can retrieve the dates without the hyphens in the first place, you'll be able to compare them with `-ge`.

Comment: Where is the else branch in this bash?

Comment: This seems to be the most correct answer. Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

There is also this method from the article titled: [Simple date and time calulation in BASH](http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/31944-simple-date-time-calulation-bash.html) from unix.com.

*These functions are an excerpt from a [script in that thread!](http://www.unix.com/302092271-post1.html)*

```
date2stamp () {
    date --utc --date "$1" +%s
}

dateDiff (){
    case $1 in
        -s)   sec=1;      shift;;
        -m)   sec=60;     shift;;
        -h)   sec=3600;   shift;;
        -d)   sec=86400;  shift;;
        *)    sec=86400;;
    esac
    dte1=$(date2stamp $1)
    dte2=$(date2stamp $2)
    diffSec=$((dte2-dte1))
    if ((diffSec < 0)); then abs=-1; else abs=1; fi
    echo $((diffSec/sec*abs))
}
```

#### Usage

```
# calculate the number of days between 2 dates
    # -s in sec. | -m in min. | -h in hours  | -d in days (default)
    dateDiff -s "2006-10-01" "2006-10-31"
    dateDiff -m "2006-10-01" "2006-10-31"
    dateDiff -h "2006-10-01" "2006-10-31"
    dateDiff -d "2006-10-01" "2006-10-31"
    dateDiff  "2006-10-01" "2006-10-31"
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the `date` that ships with macOS.

Comment: If you install gdate on MacOS via brew this can be easily modified to work by changing `date` to `gdate`.

Comment: This answer was very helpful on my case. It should rate up!

Answer (score 1):

I convert the Strings into unix-timestamps (seconds since 1.1.1970 0:0:0).
These can compared easily

```
unix_todate=$(date -d "${todate}" "+%s")
unix_cond=$(date -d "${cond}" "+%s")
if [ ${unix_todate} -ge ${unix_cond} ]; then
   echo "over condition"
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the `date` that ships with macOS.

Comment: Seems to be the same as http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170982/100397 which was posted some time before yours

Answer (score 1):

### [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) specific answer

As I like to reduce forks and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) do permit a lot of tricks, there is my purpose:

```
todate=2013-07-18
cond=2013-07-15
```

Well, now:

```
{ read todate; read cond ;} < <(date -f - +%s <<<"$todate"$'\n'"$cond")
```

This will re-populate both variables `$todate` and `$cond`, using only one fork, with ouptut of `date -f -` wich take *stdio* for reading one date by line.

Finally, you could break your loop with

```
((todate>=cond))&&break
```

Or as a *function*:

```
myfunc() {
    local todate cond
    { read todate
      read cond
    } < <(
      date -f - +%s <<<"$1"$'\n'"$2"
    )
    ((todate>=cond))&&return
    printf "%(%a %d %b %Y)T older than %(%a %d %b %Y)T...\n" $todate $cond
}
```

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s builtin `printf` wich could render date time with *seconds from epoch* (see `man bash`;-)

This script only use one fork.

### Alternative with limited forks and date reader function

This will create a dedicated subprocess (only one fork):

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
exec 99> >(exec stdbuf -i 0 -o 0 date -f - +%s >/tmp/fifo 2>&1)
exec 98</tmp/fifo
rm /tmp/fifo
```

As input and output are open, fifo entry could be deleted.

The function:

```
myDate() {
    local var="${@:$#}"
    shift
    echo >&99 "${@:1:$#-1}"
    read -t .01 -u 98 $var
}
```

**Nota** In order to prevent useless forks like `todate=$(myDate 2013-07-18)`, the variable is to be set by the function himself. And to permit free syntax (with or without quotes to datestring), the variable name **must be the last** argument.

Then date comparission:

```
myDate 2013-07-18        todate
myDate Mon Jul 15 2013   cond
(( todate >= cond )) && {
    printf "To: %(%c)T > Cond: %(%c)T\n" $todate $cond
    break
}
```

may render:

```
To: Thu Jul 18 00:00:00 2013 > Cond: Mon Jul 15 00:00:00 2013
bash: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

if outside of a loop.

#### Or use shell-connector bash function:

```
wget https://github.com/F-Hauri/Connector-bash/raw/master/shell_connector.bash
```

or

```
wget https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/shell_connector.sh
```

(Wich are not exactly same: `.sh` do contain full test script if not sourced)

```
source shell_connector.sh
newConnector /bin/date '-f - +%s' @0 0

myDate 2013-07-18        todate
myDate "Mon Jul 15 2013"   cond
(( todate >= cond )) && {
    printf "To: %(%c)T > Cond: %(%c)T\n" $todate $cond
    break
}
```

Comment: [Profiling bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20855353/1765658) contain a good demonstration for how using `date -f -` could reduce ressources requirement.

Answer (score 0):

dates are strings, not integers; you can't compare them with standard arithmetic operators.

one approach you can use, if the separator is guaranteed to be `-`:

```
IFS=-
read -ra todate <<<"$todate"
read -ra cond <<<"$cond"
for ((idx=0;idx<=numfields;idx++)); do
  (( todate[idx] > cond[idx] )) && break
done
unset IFS
```

This works as far back as `bash 2.05b.0(1)-release`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use mysql's builtin function to compare the dates. It gives the result in 'days'.

```
from_date="2015-01-02"
date_today="2015-03-10"
diff=$(mysql -u${DBUSER} -p${DBPASSWORD} -N -e"SELECT DATEDIFF('${date_today}','${from_date}');")
```

Just insert the values of `$DBUSER` and `$DBPASSWORD` variables according to yours.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: on Mac, it seems feeding just a date like "2017-05-05" into date will append the current time to the date and you will get different value each time you convert it to epoch time. to get a more consistent epoch time for fixed dates, include dummy values for hours, minutes, and seconds:

```
date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "2017-05-05 00:00:00" +"%s"
```

This may be a oddity limited to the version of date that shipped with macOS.... tested on macOS 10.12.6.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing @Gilles answer ("The operator -ge only works with integers"), here is an example.

```
curr_date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
echo "$curr_date"
2019-06-20

old_date="2019-06-19"
echo "$old_date"
2019-06-19
```

`datetime` integer conversions to `epoch`, per @mike-q's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990949/convert-date-time-string-to-epoch-in-bash :

```
curr_date_int=$(date -d "${curr_date}" +"%s")
echo "$curr_date_int"
1561014000

old_date_int=$(date -d "${old_date}" +"%s")
echo "$old_date_int"
1560927600
```

`"$curr_date"` is greater than (more recent than) `"$old_date"`, but this expression incorrectly evaluates as `False`:

```
if [[ "$curr_date" -ge "$old_date" ]]; then echo 'foo'; fi
```

... shown explicitly, here:

```
if [[ "$curr_date" -ge "$old_date" ]]; then echo 'foo'; else echo 'bar'; fi
bar
```

**Integer comparisons:**

```
if [[ "$curr_date_int" -ge "$old_date_int" ]]; then echo 'foo'; fi
foo

if [[ "$curr_date_int" -gt "$old_date_int" ]]; then echo 'foo'; fi
foo

if [[ "$curr_date_int" -lt "$old_date_int" ]]; then echo 'foo'; fi

if [[ "$curr_date_int" -lt "$old_date_int" ]]; then echo 'foo'; else echo 'bar'; fi
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this comparison doesn't work well with a hyphenated date string is the shell assumes a number with a leading 0 is an octal, in this case the month "07".  There have been various solutions proposed but the quickest and easiest is to strip out the hyphens. Bash has a string substitution feature that makes this quick and easy then the comparison can be performed as an arithmetic expression:

```
todate=2013-07-18
cond=2013-07-15

if (( ${todate//-/} > ${cond//-/} ));
then
    echo larger
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all or most of the answers so far either assume you get to specify date format (which the question does not explicitly specify one way or the other), or assume that you have a feature rich version of date command or something.

Sometimes though, you are not in control of the date's format (e.g., the expiration date of an SSL certificate where date is given by a month name abbreviation) and you don't have access to a fancier date command. So while this solution is not completely general, it does run on a vanilla bash shell on Linux, Solaris, and FreeBSD, and handles month names (borrows significantly from a few smart answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252383/unix-convert-month-name-to-number):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function monthnumber {
    month=$(echo ${1:0:3} | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')
    MONTHS="JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"
    tmp=${MONTHS%%$month*}
    month=${#tmp}
    monthnumber=$((month/3+1))
    printf "%02d\n" $monthnumber
}

# Or at the expense of some flexibility and brevity, you get more readability:
function monthnumber2 {
    case $(echo ${1:0:3} | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]') in
        JAN) monthnumber="01" ;;
        FEB) monthnumber="02" ;;
        MAR) monthnumber="03" ;;
        APR) monthnumber="04" ;;
        MAY) monthnumber="05" ;;
        JUN) monthnumber="06" ;;
        JUL) monthnumber="07" ;;
        AUG) monthnumber="08" ;;
        SEP) monthnumber="09" ;;
        OCT) monthnumber="10" ;;
        NOV) monthnumber="11" ;;
        DEC) monthnumber="12" ;;
    esac
    printf "%02d\n" $monthnumber
}

TODAY=$( date "+%Y%m%d" )

echo "GET /" | openssl s_client -connect github.com:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > tmp.pem
cert_expiry_date=$(openssl x509 -in tmp.pem -noout -enddate | cut -d'=' -f2)
month_name=$(echo $cert_expiry_date | cut -d' ' -f1)
month_number=$( monthnumber $month_name )
cert_expiration_datestamp=$( echo $cert_expiry_date | awk "{printf \"%d%02d%02d\",\$4,\"${month_number}\",\$2}" )

echo "compare: [ $cert_expiration_datestamp -gt $TODAY ]"
if [ $cert_expiration_datestamp -gt $TODAY ] ; then
    echo "all ok, the cert expiration date is in the future."
else
    echo "WARNING: cert expiration date is in the past."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to compare the dates of two files, you can use this:

```
if [ file1 -nt file2 ]
then
  echo "file1 is newer than file2"
fi
# or +ot for "older than"
```

See https://superuser.com/questions/188240/how-to-verify-that-file2-is-newer-than-file1-in-bash