# Looping through unix dates

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, timestamps

I have rather basic task but wasn't able to find proper solution to it.
I want to iterate date interval since 2008 to current and need epoch values for each iteration of the loop. I am interested in iterating both years, halves and months as well.
I wrote such script

```
#!/bin/bash
initial_date=`date -d "2008-02-04 00:00:00 UTC" +%s`
end_date=`date +%s`
n=0
until [ $initial_date -gt $end_date ]; do
 echo $initial_date
 let n+=1
 readable_date=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %T" -d "1970-01-01 $initial_date sec"`
 echo $readable_date
 readable_date=`date -d "$readable_date + $n year"`
 initial_date=`date -d "$readable_date" +%s`
done
```

but its output is rather weird to me:

> 1202083200 
> 2008-02-04 **00**:00:00 
> 1233702000 
> 2009-02-03 **23**:00:00
>   
> 1265230800 
> 2010-02-03 **21**:00:00 
> 1296756000 
> 2011-02-03 **18**:00:00
>   
> 1328277600 
> 2012-02-03 **15**:00:00 
> 1359885600 
> 2013-02-03 **11**:00:00
>   
> 1391403600 
> 2014-02-03 **06**:00:00 
> 1422918000 
> 2015-02-02 **23**:00:00
>   
> 1454425200 
> 2016-02-02 **15**:00:00

Why the year is not incremented properly? Shifted hours seems to me a side-effect of unix>>UTC>>unix conversion.
Is there any direct (without reconversion) method for doing this?

**P.S.**
And yes, I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706823/how-to-increment-a-date-in-a-bash-script), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84381/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-a-shell) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226229/bash-looping-through-dates) question and found no clear way of doing this. All they are based on incrementing number and converting date with the help of it which doesn't seem precise to me.

And yes, I thought about adding `60*60*24*30*365` to initial date but would it be correct? This approach doesn't consider leap years, months comprised of 31 days and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date used:

```
$ dateA="2008-02-04 00:00:00 UTC"
```

The first reason to get dates with shifted times is to request "local" dates:

```
$ date -d "$dateA"
Sun Feb  3 19:00:00 EST 2008
```

Which will be corrected if you specify a UTC time:

```
$ TZ=UTC0 date -d "$dateA"
Mon Feb  4 00:00:00 UTC 2008
```

Or better (make an habit of using it) use the `-u` option of date:

```
$ date -ud "$dateA"
Mon Feb  4 00:00:00 UTC 2008
```

A second reason is to request "relative items" with a sign:

```
$ date -ud "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T" -ud "$dateA") +1 year"  ### wrong
Tue Feb  3 23:00:00 UTC 2009

$ date -ud "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T" -ud "$dateA") 1 year"  ### better
Mon Feb  4 00:00:00 UTC 2008
```

But all the time problems (usually) go away when a "time zone" (-z) is used:

```
$ date -ud "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T %z" -ud "$dateA") +1 year"  ### Best
Wed Feb  4 00:00:00 UTC 2009

$ date -ud "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T %z" -ud "$dateA") 1 year"  ### Preferred
Wed Feb  4 00:00:00 UTC 2009
```

The issue is related to the way a date string is parsed, if the TZ value is missing, the +1 may be interpreted as a Time Zone value:

```
$ date -ud "2008-02-04 00:00:00 +3 year"
Tue Feb  3 21:00:00 UTC 2009
```

Even if an environment value for TZ has been set:

```
$ TZ=UTC0 date -ud "2008-02-04 00:00:00 +3 year"
Tue Feb  3 21:00:00 UTC 2009
```

Yes, the year was incresed **once** (2009 instead of 2008) but the `+3` was used for a change of the time presented (not what was intended).

I repeat: the problem is that the `+3` may be parsed as a Time Zone value.

---

Also, to convert (epoch) seconds to dates, GNU date may use "@"

```
$ dateAsec="$( date -ud "$dateA" +"%s" )

$ date -ud @"$dateAsec"
Mon Feb  4 00:00:00 UTC 2008
```

---

The script (using a (newdate) function) could be written like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dateI="$(date -ud "2008-02-04 00:00:00 UTC" +%s)"
dateF="$(date -u +%s)"

newdate(){ date -ud "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T %z" -ud @"$dateI") $1 year" +"%s"; }

n=0
while 
    dateN="$( newdate "$n" )"
    (( dateN < dateF ));
do
    dateNhuman="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T %z" -ud @"$dateN")"
    echo "dateN=$dateN --- $dateNhuman ---> $dateF $(( $dateF - $dateN )) $n"
    (( n++ ))
done
```

Results:

```
dateN=1202083200 --- 2008-02-04 00:00:00 +0000 ---> 1470543626 268460426 0
dateN=1233705600 --- 2009-02-04 00:00:00 +0000 ---> 1470543626 236838026 1
dateN=1265241600 --- 2010-02-04 00:00:00 +0000 ---> 1470543626 205302026 2
dateN=1296777600 --- 2011-02-04 00:00:00 +0000 ---> 1470543626 173766026 3
dateN=1328313600 --- 2012-02-04 00:00:00 +0000 ---> 1470543626 142230026 4
dateN=1359936000 --- 2013-02-04 00:00:00 +0000 ---> 1470543626 110607626 5
dateN=1391472000 --- 2014-02-04 00:00:00 +0000 ---> 1470543626 79071626 6
dateN=1423008000 --- 2015-02-04 00:00:00 +0000 ---> 1470543626 47535626 7
dateN=1454544000 --- 2016-02-04 00:00:00 +0000 ---> 1470543626 15999626 8
```

All years appear and all seems correct.

Comment: BTW, what is the difference between signed and unsigned relative items? The first sample is marked as _wrong_ by you and the second one as _best_ ^)

Comment: What concerns time zone: the more elegant way I found is to specify it throughout the script. It can be done via `export TZ=UTC` statement in the beginning of file.

Comment: @Suncatcher *Wrong* has the time changed. *Best* is using the `%z` (time zone) indication (which avoids the signed isssue).

Comment: @Suncatcher The correct value should be `UTC0`, three letters (an optional sign) and a digit. There are systems that may not default to `utc` time with some odd string (GNU does). Try `TZ=sdshdk`.

Comment: @Suncatcher Please read added detail after the "Preferred" line. A global setting of `UTC0` will not ensure a correct parsing of the date in all cases. As shown: `TZ=UTC0 date -ud "2008-02-04 00:00:00 +3 year"` will still fail.

Comment: so we shouldn't use signed relatives ever?

Comment: @Suncatcher I am merely describing the problem: using signed relatives without a explicit and correct Time Zone value may lead to incorrect parsing. As explicitly shown in my answer (please do read it), signed values could be used if the Time Zone is included in the time string to be parsed (the line tagged `best`). The conclusion to never use signed relatives is yours only.

Answer (score 3):

An iterator on a [relative date](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#Relative-items-in-date-strings) from the starting point may make more sense:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

START='2008-02-04 00:00:00 UTC'
END=$( date +%s )

for yearnum in $( seq 1 999 ); do
  NUDATE=$( date -d "$START + $yearnum year" +%s )
  PUNY_HUMAN_DATE=$( date -d "@$NUDATE" "+%Y-%m-%d %T %Z" )
  if [[ $NUDATE -gt $END ]]; then
    break
  fi
  echo $NUDATE $PUNY_HUMAN_DATE
done
```

Which results in something like:

```
-bash-4.1$ bash iter
1233705600 2009-02-04 00:00:00 UTC
1265241600 2010-02-04 00:00:00 UTC
1296777600 2011-02-04 00:00:00 UTC
1328313600 2012-02-04 00:00:00 UTC
1359936000 2013-02-04 00:00:00 UTC
1391472000 2014-02-04 00:00:00 UTC
1423008000 2015-02-04 00:00:00 UTC
1454544000 2016-02-04 00:00:00 UTC
-bash-4.1$
```

Comment: There are need not *variables* and **echo** `date -d "$START + $yearnum year" +"%s %Y-%m-%d %T %Z"`

Comment: Thanks for good and compact script. My problem was that I didn't consider time zones and wasn't aware of syntax `$X + $Y years +%s` where relative items can be used together with `%s` format.

Comment: However, such output is true only if the system time zone is UTC which is not my case. To make it work like this one should explicitly specify timezone `TZ=UTC`